# Ошибка при подключении к репозиторию bitbucket

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, bitbucket

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть проблема, пытаюсь подключится к репозиторию, при вводе пароля выдает ошибку (я уверен что пароль правильный, проверял). Я новичок в этой теме, не знаю куда двигатся чтобы решить эту проблему. Хелп)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: [с картинками](https://jeka.by/post/1051/setup-ssh-keys-for-bitbucket-github/)